# Limit number of checkboxes checked inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

So I have javascript code that checks how much checkboxes is checked. It works well except that when I hit 4 checkboxes it disables **all** checkboxes not only unchecked (you can see it on image below). Thank you!

JAVASCRIPT

```
$scope.checkedb= function (unit, device, unitt){
  unitt.showcb = !unitt.showcb;

 numOfCh = 0;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < unit.length; i ++){
    if (unit[i].showcb == true){
      numOfCh ++;
    }

    if (numOfCh > 3){
      device.selectedf = true;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="unit in data[unitIndex].units" ng-if="unit.users_ID == tvw.id">

        <td class="footable-visible" > 

           <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="device.selectedf" ng-click="checkedb(data[unitIndex].units, device, unit)">

        </td> 
</div>
```

[image: dasd]as you can see the checked checkboxes are also disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to itterate through the array of checkboxes again after you selected more than 3, and see wich checkbox is selected and disable only them.

What you are doing now is to disable all checkboxes when you have checked more than 3. device.selectedf = true;

```
if (numOfCh > 3){
  if ( "this checkbox is checked" ){
    do this on this checkbox => device.selectedf = true;
  }
}
```

So I have a little hard time reading your code, but this might be a solution in the right direction for you:

```
$scope.checkedb = function (unit, device, unitt){
  unitt.showcb = !unitt.showcb;

  var numOfCh = 0;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < unit.length; i ++){
    if (unit[i].showcb == true){
      numOfCh ++;
    }

    if (numOfCh > 3){
      disableCheckboxes();
      return;
    }
  }
}

function disableCheckboxes(unit, device, unitt){
     unitt.showcb = !unitt.showcb;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < unit.length; i ++){
        if (unit[i].showcb == false){
            unit[i].device.selectedf = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.
/Zorken17

Comment: I understand that I have to check wich one are selected but this is where I need help. How to check it? Thanks !

Comment: Make a "working" JSFiddle fore us to test your code, and after that it will be easyer to help. @JMusic

Comment: I have now edited my code above, check it out and hope it guides you in the right direction. @JMusic

Comment: Thank you, it will definitly help me. Will "play" around with that and when it starts working I will let you know. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('DomReadyCtrl', function($timeout, $scope){
  var maxChk = 4;
    $scope.units = [
     { checked: false },
        { checked: false },
        { checked: false },
        { checked: false },
        { checked: false },
        { checked: false },
        { checked: false }
    ];
$scope.checkedb = function() {
      return $scope.units.filter(
       function(unit) {return unit.checked; }).length >= maxChk;
    };
});
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DomReadyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="unit in units">
    <td class="footable-visible" > 
      <input ng-model="unit.checked" ng-disabled="!unit.checked && checkedb()" type="checkbox" />{{unit.name}}
    </td> 
  </div> 
</div>
```